# Not able no update Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I have **Ubuntu 18.04** and **python 3.7**.

```
uname -a
Linux my-dell-laptop 4.15.0-109-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 02:39:32 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get this error :

```
E: The repository 'http://dl.bintray.com/aluxian/deb stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/aluxian/deb dev Release' does not have a Release file.
N: 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: You can update Ubuntu, but you've added a source that doesn't match your release. Everything else works OK.

Comment: The repository in question seems not to be there (anymore). It may have been removed by its maintainers, or it may not or no longer offer packages for the Ubuntu version you're using. Or maybe its address changed. Any other repositories you have in your setup should still be working (unless they have problems of their own).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same problem and solved it myself recently.
I went to Software and Updates->Other Software unticked `https://dl.bintray.com/aluxian/deb` repo. Then the `sudo apt-get update` problem was solved !!!

Hope this helps.